# Find the value of symmetric function $\sum{\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-functions

> If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ and $\delta$ be the roots of the equation $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s=0$, $s\neq 0$, find the value of symmetric function $$\sum{\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}}$$

We have $\sum \alpha =-p, ~~~~\sum\alpha\beta=q, ~~~\sum \alpha\beta\gamma =-r$ and $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta=s$. But how to use them to get the desired result. Please help.

I wrote $$\sum{\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma^2}}=\frac{\sum\alpha^3\beta^3\delta^2}{s^2}$$ But I think it becoms more complicated.

Comment: You need to specify whether the sum is over all combinations of three roots, or over only combinations of three distinct roots.  In other words, if the roots were $\{1,2,3,4\}$ would the term $$\frac{1\cdot 2}{1^2}$$ be part of the sum or not?

Comment: @MarkFischler there are four roots. Also $\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha^2}$ like terms are not there.